# What the difference about LOCAL_CFLAGS vs APP_CFLAGS ？

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

In the Android.mk, I can use 
`LOCAL_CFLAGS += ...` to specify flag to compiler. also, I can use: 
`./ndk-build APP_CFLAGS += ....`

What's the difference between these two flags?

Comment: sorry!!! my question is:"what the difference about LOCAL_CFLAGS vs APP_CFLAGS ？"

Answer (score 1):

- `LOCAL_CFLAGS` is applied to *the current* module, and is undefined after an `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`.
- `APP_CFLAGS` is applied to *all* modules.